# How to reproduce the following IntegrityError in django unit test?

Tags: python, django

I have two models "Question" and "Font". In these "Question" is a non-deletable model. And Question has a reference to Font.

So If a font is deleted, then font's reference in question will be set to none and if a question is deleted then since question is a non-deletable model it won't be deleted from DB its active field will be set to False, so it can't be queried through Django's 'objects' model manager. In this case, if I delete a question and after that, if I try to delete the font it throws 'IntegrityError' since soft deleted question still has reference to the font.

The problem is I can't be able to reproduce this in the unit test. In the unit test font is getting deleted gracefully. 
In frontend, I get the following.

```
update or delete on table "custom_fonts_customfont" violates foreign key constraint "font_id_refs_id_794a5361" on table "questions_question"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1026) is still referenced from table "questions_question".
```

I tried using Django's Transaction test case, I also made sure that question is soft deleted in the test case and confirmed question's reference to the font by using Django's 'unfiltered' model manager.

```py
class Question(ExtendedOrderedModel, NonDeletableModel):
      font = models.ForeignKey('custom_fonts.CustomFont', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

This is my test case

```py
    def test_font_deletion_after_question_deletion_(self):
        self.question.font = CustomFont.objects.create(
            name='roboto', font_type='truetype', path='font.ttf', created_by=self.owner
        )
        self.question.save()
        self.question.delete()

        CustomFont.objects.all().delete() # This should raise an error but it is not raising

        print(Question.objects.all()) # []
        print(Question.unfiltered.first().font_id) # 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I found the reason. It is because

> In Postgresql, constraints are set DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED. This
>   causes it to only check those constraints when the transaction is
>   committed. (This may affect the Oracle backend, too, based on a quick
>   search.) This causes a problem with TestCase: as they're never
>   committed, many constraint violations can never be triggered.

Adding the following lines in my test case helped me.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET CONSTRAINTS ALL IMMEDIATE')
```

source : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11665